How to configure wrangler to not minify function names?
I know that in webpack you can do a keep_fnames: true with the TerserPlugin but can I do a similar thing with wrangler ?
I am using hono cloudflare worker template and I use this command to deploy my code wrangler deploy --minify src/index.ts
My use case is that I want to use .name method in my code
function getTodoFnName(): string {
  return getTodoFnName.name;
}

